# How to find percent of whole grouped by a value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, analytics, data-analysis

I have 2 tables

`Table 1`

```
| order_id | remade_or_not |    
| ---      | ---           |  
| 1        | true          |  
| 2        | false         |  
| 3        | true          |
```

`Table 2`

```
| order_id | maker_id |  
| ---      | ---      |  
| 1        | 101      |   
| 2        | 101      |  
| 3        | 102      |
```

How do I find the `remade_or_not` percentage for every `maker_id` in PostgreSQL? The two tables can be joined on the `order_id`.
For e.g., what is the percentage where `remade_or_not` = `true` for `maker_id` `101`.

Comment: What is a "`remade_or_not` percentage"? Please share desired results so we can understand how to calculate this percentage to help solve for you.

Comment: @JNevill I need to find the percentage of whether the order was remade or not for each `maker_id`. For example, say a `maker_id` had 5 orders out of which one had to be remade. This means 20% of the orders had to be remade for that `maker_id`. I want to know a SQL statement to find this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `remade_or_not` is already a boolean column, then you can cast it to `int` and take the `avg()`:

```
select t2.maker_id, avg(t1.remade_or_not::int) as remade_pct
  from table_1 t1
       join table_2 t2 
         on t2.order_id = t1.order_id
 group by t2.maker_id;
```

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d5a022466d452b1651925c3b0bba1e32)

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. Could you please explain to me what is happening in the `remade_pct` column? How exactly are we getting the right answer? I would appreciate it if you could help me understand this code.

Comment: @an_analyst If the `remade_or_not` column is a `boolean` (true/false), that `boolean` can be cast to an `integer` that will be `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`.  Take the average of the 0 and 1 values, and that will result in the percentage.  For example, if there are three with three remade and two not remade, then the `remade_pct` will be `(1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0) / 5`, or `0.6`, or 60%.

Answer (score 1):

try like below using conditional aggregation I assume remade_or_not is string data type in case it is bool then condition will be changed in side case

```
select maker_id,
(coalesce(sum(case when remade_or_not='true' then 1 else 0),0)*1.00/count(order_id))*100
    from   tab1 t1 jon tab2 t2 on t1.order_id=t2.order_id group by maker_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You take the count of orders by maker id and remade or not value and divide it by the total count of orders by maker id. If you want this expressed as a decimal between 0 and 100, change the 1.0 to 100.0.

```
SELECT x.maker_id
     , y.remade_or_not
     , COUNT(*) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY x.maker_id) AS pct
FROM table2 x
     INNER JOIN table1 y ON x.order_id = y.order_id
GROUP BY x.maker_id
       , y.remade_or_not;
```